# Group By with Multiple Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I believe a Group By would solve the following, but maybe it's Select Distinct.  Either way, I respectfully turn to you:

The Goal:

To consolidate by Agreement then LaborCode then Schedule.  I work for a company that performs multiple services and I want to take any range of dates and specify what DAYS OF THE WEEK we perform each service.  Over the period of a month we would have (4) Mondays - I want to just see ONE Monday.  As a side note, I have tried XML Path but it doesn't seem to work.

The Code:

```
Select Top 100 Percent Agreements.AgrmntID, JobSites.SiteName,
  Customers.CompanyName, LaborCodeTypes.Description As LaborCode, DateName(dw,
  AgreementSchedules.SchedDate) as Schedule
From Agreements Inner Join
  AgreementSchedules On Agreements.AgrmntID = AgreementSchedules.AgrmntID
  Inner Join
  Customers On Agreements.CustID = Customers.CustID Inner Join
  JobSites On Agreements.CustSiteID = JobSites.CustSiteID Left Outer Join
  LaborCodeTypes On AgreementSchedules.RepairID = LaborCodeTypes.RepairID
Where Agreements.Status = 2
```

The Data (Schedule is derived from AgreementSchedules.SchedDate) - 2 weeks selected:

```
AgrmntID    SiteName   Company   LaborCode    Schedule
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
1           JOB01      COMP01    Sweeping     Monday
1           JOB01      COMP01    Sweeping     Wednesday
1           JOB01      COMP01    Sweeping     Monday
1           JOB01      COMP01    Sweeping     Wednesday
1           JOB01      COMP01    Porter       Thursday
1           JOB01      COMP01    Porter       Thursday
2           JOB02      COMP02    Landscaping  Tuesday
2           JOB02      COMP02    Landscaping  Tuesday
```

The Desired Output:

```
AgrmntID    SiteName   Company   LaborCode    Schedule
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
1           JOB01      COMP01    Sweeping     Monday
1           JOB01      COMP01    Sweeping     Wednesday
1           JOB01      COMP01    Porter       Thursday
2           JOB02      COMP02    Landscaping  Tuesday
```

Thank you SO much in advance.  I've been trying to figure this out for days with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either would work.

I'd go for DISTINCT

```
Select DISTINCT Agreements.AgrmntID, JobSites.SiteName, 
  Customers.CompanyName, LaborCodeTypes......
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!  Wow - I can't believe how much time I wasted making this wayyyy more complicated than it needed to be.

Answer (score 1):

A distinct should work just fine here..

FYI `Group by` and `Distinct` are essentially equivalent to each other (in fact this is how some databases implement DISTINCT).

Note, Distinct is faster as it doesnt sort the results

Also, using Distinct is cleaner and easier to read and maintain.. Other readers of your code will immediately get the intent..

Comment: Thank you!!  ...umm, would you mind taking the time to show me how??  I can't, for the life of me, figure it out.